# Mapping all characters into another set of characters in R for a string using list

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, character, stringr

How do I efficiently modify a a single string (which is to be part of a column) according to a predefined dictionary (named list) of character mappings?

Suppose I had the mapping:

```
map <- list('a' = 'u', 'e' = 'i', 'i' = 'o', 'o' = 'a', 'u' = 'e')
```

And the character vector:

```
imp_text <- c('aei', 'ou ei', 'iua oe')
```

I would like to apply some function to `imp_text` and obtain

```
c('uio' , 'ae io', 'oeu ai')
```

Where each character was translated according to the associations defined in `map`. In the future, `map` might contain a mapping for the entire alphabet, and `imp_text` might contain a very large amount of entries. How do I accomplish this? I would prefer a tidyverse approach but anything's welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
chartr(paste0(names(map), collapse=""), paste(map, collapse=""), imp_text)
# [1] "uio"    "ae io"  "oeu ai"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: `paste(..,collapse=)` collapses a set of strings into a single string, separated by nothing, so the first reduces to `"aeiou"`, the second reduces to `"uioae"`. [`chartr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html) just translates from each character in the first with each character in the second.

Comment: Ok, that is a great answer. I am thinking I could deal with the presence of uppercase letters by extending the `````map```` mapping and then applying the above all at once. Is there a more efficient way of dealing with mixed case letters when I need to preserve the original case?

Comment: no, this is designed for case-sensitive operations, so something like `"aAeEiIoOuU"` and `"uUoOiIeEaA"`.

Comment: One of those great answers because it uses a relatively obscure function which is simple and very fast to execute. I tried something with string-splitting and indexing and got nowhere close.